# Add menu option to "New Post" menu in admin bar

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu, add-menu-page

I'm trying to figure out how to add an item to the new menu bar.  To be clear, I know how to add items to the menu bar. I want to add something new under the bug plus sign in the admin bar.  Here's a pic of the admin bar I'm looking to add an item to.

[image: Pic of what I want to do]

The code from my plugin looks like this.

```
        $args = array(
        'id'     => 'test1234',     // id of the existing child node (New > Post)
        'title'  => 'test', // alter the title of existing node
        'parent' => 'new-link',          // set parent to false to make it a top level (parent) node
        'href'  => admin_url('admin.php?page=enter_timesheet')
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
```

I'm assuming I just need to modify the 'parent' tag to something, but I'm not sure what.  I've found this to be shockingly poorly documented (or my Bingle-foo is failing me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `new-content` :

```
function make_parent_node($wp_admin_bar) {
    $args = array(
        'id' => 'test1234', // id of the existing child node (New > Post)
        'title' => 'test', // alter the title of existing node
        'parent' => 'new-content', // set parent to false to make it a top level (parent) node
        'href' => admin_url('admin.php?page=enter_timesheet')
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}
```

it will show at the bottom:

[image]

you can see the `ID` of the `parent node` in the HTML if you dont want to dig in the core files:

[image]

they will be like `wp-admin-bar-{ID-name}`